# What is the '-235' in this question?

Tags: nuclear-physics, notation, elements, isotopes

I am self-studying higher level physics currently, and stumbled upon this question:

> $1 mg$ of uranium - $235$ is completely destroyed in an atomic bomb. How much energy is liberated?

I do not understand what is the '$-235$' in this question. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Ah! Self-studying. Still not a conceptual question. You need to do some research before posting a question at this site.

Comment: Uranium-235 is an isotope of Uranium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question that you have been asked is a poor and misleading question.

[Uranium-235](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-235) is an isotope of uranium with 92 protons and 143 neutrons in its nucleus. Uranium enriched with the uranium-235 isotope is used in atomic bombs because this isotope sustains a nuclear chain reaction, unlike the more common and more stable isotope uranium-238, which has 92 protons and 146 neutrons in its nucleus.

However, I think this is irrelevant to the answer. I think the question is expecting you to apply $E=mc^2$, so the question could use any substance instead of uranium-235 and the answer would be the same. Also, this is a misleading question because it implies that uranium-235 is completely annihilated in a atomic bomb, which is incorrect. When an atom of uranium-235 fissions it splits into smaller nuclei (fission products), and only a small proportion of its binding energy is released as radiation.

Answer (score 7):

Uranium has 92 protons.  If an atom has 92 protons, it is a uranium atom.

But a particular uranium atom might have anywhere from 140 neutrons to 146 neutrons.  The different numbers of neutrons mark different *isotopes* of uranium.

An isotope is named according to the total number of protons *and* neutrons in its nucleus.  For example, a uranium atom with 92 protons and 146 neutrons has a total of 238 nucleons and is an atom of the isotope called U-238.  U-238 is the most common isotope of uranium.

U-235 has 92 protons and 143 neutrons.  The isotope is relatively rare; it makes up less than 1% of uranium in nature.

If you look at the [Wikipedia page for U-235](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-235), under the Fission properties section there is some information about the energy released by fission of a single atom of the isotope.

Comment: So, how do I solve this question? With steps, please.

Comment: The Wikipedia article tells you how much energy is released when a single atom of U-238 decays by fission.  But you have 1mg of U-238, which is a lot more than 1 atom.  I'll leave you to work out how many exactly.  Hint: there are around about 238 atomic mass units in one U-238 atom, and an atomic mass unit has a mass in grams that isn't hard to find.

Comment: @ArpitaE. I don't think the question is asking how much energy is released if 1mg of U-235 fissions. It asks how much energy is released if 1mg of U-235 is *completely destroyed*. I believe this is expecting you to apply $E=mc^2$. This is, of course, entirely different from (and much greater than) the energy that is released in fission, when U-235 decays into fission products but is not completely destroyed. This is why I think this is a poor and misleading question - see my answer below.

Comment: > So, how do I solve this question? With steps, please.

["solve my homework" problems are not answered here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

'$235$' is the mass number of that Uranium isotope. Uranium has mainly two isotopes [Uranium-238](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-238) and [Uranium-235](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-235). We sometimes represent the mass number of elements along with their names.
Examples :

- Plutonium-241
- Carbon-14

> [**Isotope:**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotope)
> Isotopes are variants of a particular chemical element which differ in neutron number. All isotopes of a given element have the same number of protons but different numbers of neutrons in each atom.

Your question asks to calculate the amount of energy liberated when a milligram of U-235 is destroyed. Almost $200MeV$(Megaelectronvolts) of energy is released in the fission of U-235 per atom. Which is roughly equal to $3.2*10^{-11}$ joule.

Answer (score 1):

The -235 is the [isotope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotope) number of uranium. Certain elements have different "versions" with the same number of protons and electrons, but a varying number of neutrons. "Heavy water", for example, is water where the hydrogen is actually deuterium (the name for the hydrogen isotope with an additional neutron in its core).